# C++ std::map sort strings by length then by alpha

Tags: c++, stdmap

Sometime ago I've noticed the following algorithm to sort std::map:

```
struct cmp_str {
    // To facilitate TStringWrapper key in std::map
    bool operator()(const TStringWrapper& a, const TStringWrapper& b) {
        bool isLessThan = false;
        if (a.length() < b.length()) {
            isLessThan = true;
        } else if (a.length() > b.length()) {
            isLessThan = false;
        } else {
            isLessThan = memcmp(a.get(), b.get(), std::min(b.length(), b.length())) < 0;
        }
        return isLessThan;
    }
};

std::map<TStringWrapper, TObj*,  cmp_str> m_map;
```

So wondering which side effects this might have (except non-pure alpha ordering) or is it completely safe to use in std::map (and it should be even more efficient than comparing by string values).